# Database restoring

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I stopped a database restoring job containing recovery immediately in script, Now the database was in restoring state. How to make it online ASAP.

Comment: Read the docs?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/restart-an-interrupted-restore-operation-transact-sql

Comment: How exactly were you restoring and what's the current state?

Comment: Running  the restore  script in a sql server agent job, immediately stop the job after initiating it. Now the db was in restoring state. I want to known, how to make online immediately.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
restore database databasename with recovery
```

Comment: This will bring the database back to online in sec. downvote could explain why so that I could learn new stuff lol

Comment: Thank you Long, i run the same script again to complete the restore process.   I will try your suggestion next, if it happened again. Hope it won't happen again.

Comment: usually database `restoring` status meaning it is waiting the latest .TRN(if you name transaction log backup file as it)